# R Recover original data.frame from model.frame

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression, lm, mgcv

In R, you can fit GAM models from the `mgcv` package using a formula which contains transformations such as `log` or `sqrt` and by default the `model.frame` is returned (only the variables specified in the formula with transformations applied).

Is there any way I can recover the untransformed `data.frame`?

**Example:**

`reg <- mgcv::gam(log(mpg) ~ disp + I(hp^2), data=mtcars)`

returns

`> head(reg$model,3)
              log(mpg) disp I(hp^2)
Mazda RX4     3.044522  160   12100
Mazda RX4 Wag 3.044522  160   12100
Datsun 710    3.126761  108    8649`

But, I want to get this **untransformed** dataset from the model's `model.frame`

`mpg disp  hp
Mazda RX4     21.0  160 110
Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0  160 110
Datsun 710    22.8  108  93`

**Some Background**: The `newdata` argument for most model's `predict()` function requires untransformed data, so I cannot feed the `model.frame` back into the `predict()` function. I am already aware that the omitting the `newdata` argument will return fitted values. My requirement is that the model object gives me back the raw data.

Comment: Is there an easy way to programmatically reverse every transform? I don't want to write custom code to parse the column names and then apply certain functions.

Comment: Transformations aren't necessarily invertible. In your example you use `hp^2`, which isn't invertible because it loses the sign of `hp`. The smooth transformations used in `mgcv` are certainly not invertible - they make it very possible to map two different input values to the same output. The only practical way to do this is to keep the data, as in Zheyuan's answer.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this issue? I could use a solution to this problem myself

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way: use `glm` instead of `lm`, even for Gaussian data. `glm` returns much more stuff than `lm`, including the raw data frame.

---

Well, if you are asking `mgcv` questions, you'd better provide a `mgcv` example.

`mgcv` has a consistent standard with `glm`. Have a read on `?gamObject` for a full list of what `gam` can return. You will see that it can return `data`, if you set `keepData` via `control` argument of `gam`. When you call `gam`, add the following

```
control = gam.control(keepData = TRUE)
```

Here is a simple, reproducible example:

```
dat <- data.frame(x = runif(50), y = rnorm(50))
library(mgcv)
fit <- gam(y ~ s(x, bs = 'cr', k = 5), data = dat, control = gam.control(keepData = TRUE))
head(fit$model)  # model frame
head(fit$data)  # original data
```

Comment: This is actually for a `gam` and it also does not provide this info

Comment: It's a `mgcv` model, not a `gam`. The `gam` package actually does return the data as part of the model object.

Comment: You can provide the `keep.data` argument to `mgcv::gam()` without error, but it still does not return the raw data. It still only returns the `model.frame`.

Answer (score 3):

We can extract the `vars` from the 'terms' and use it to subset the original dataset

```
head(mtcars[all.vars(reg$terms)], 3)
#               mpg disp  hp
#Mazda RX4     21.0  160 110
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0  160 110
#Datsun 710    22.8  108  93
```

---

Or with `call`

```
v1 <- all.vars(reg$call)
head(get(tail(v1, 1))[head(v1, -1)], 3)
#               mpg disp  hp
#Mazda RX4     21.0  160 110
#Mazda RX4 Wag 21.0  160 110
#Datsun 710    22.8  108  93
```

Comment: You can see in my post that my requirement is that the model object gives me back the raw data. You cannot assume that the dataset has been loaded or even exists in the global environment.

Comment: @StevenMortimer  I am extracting the terms only from the model.  Otherwise, you have to do the transformation based on the model object as the original dataset is not present

Comment: I understand that the terms come from the model object in your example, but I need the raw, untransformed data from the model object. I assume from the `model.frame` since that is the only thing resembling the raw data.

Comment: @StevenMortimer  If there is no orginal object, the model object doesn't have the orignal dataset (as per the model showed in the example).  if the original object is available, the second option (updated) works too

Comment: @StevenMortimer  Perhaps `eval(getCall(reg)$data, environment(formula(reg)))[all.vars(reg$terms)]` if working in the same env.  Otherwise, if the model object don't have any info to get the original data, it may not be easy

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Based on comments by @李哲源 Zheyuan Li

The following approach depends on original data to be present in the current workspace or in the search path. If we remove original data before updating the model, it will produce an error.

> `Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'dat' not found`

```
dat <- mtcars
reg <- lm(log(mpg) ~ disp + I(hp^2), data=dat)
head(reg$model,3)
#               log(mpg) disp I(hp^2)
# Mazda RX4     3.044522  160   12100
# Mazda RX4 Wag 3.044522  160   12100
# Datsun 710    3.126761  108    8649

# rm( dat )  ## uncomment this line and see error appears after update
reg <- update(reg, mpg ~ disp + hp, method = 'model.frame' )
head(reg)
#                    mpg disp  hp
# Mazda RX4         21.0  160 110
# Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160 110
# Datsun 710        22.8  108  93
# Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258 110
# Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360 175
# Valiant           18.1  225 105
```

Comment: This answer does not address the question. The question shows that you can retrieve the `model.frame` from the object, but you cannot get back the untransformed data in an easy way.